# Angularjs - How to store objects in an array and local storage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How I can store multiple objects into an array and then into local storage so that I can get all objects when required using a loop.

example objects:

```
var newMsg = {
      sentDate: msgDate,
      sentTime: msgTime,
      msgTitle: "message title",
      msgDesc: "message desc"
    };
```

Currently I'm using https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#configuration-example angularjs module but struggling to store and retrieve objects from an array.

I have tried the following code:

```
msgArray = [];
var savedMsgs = localStorageService.set("wimmtkey", newMsg);

    msgArray.push(savedMsgs); 
    console.log(savedMsgs);
```

This outputs 'true' in the  console but expecting to see the stored object. Please also advise to loop through the array to retrieve the objects. Thanks.

Comment: in general you want to push the objects in the array, then set the array in the localStorage using the set method.
When you want to get the array back you will have to use the get method

Answer (score 5):

Some more code would be useful but for [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) this is the way that you push objects into array before saving the array in the localStorage:

```
var msgArray = [];
var newMsg = {
    sentDate: msgDate,
    sentTime: msgTime,
    msgTitle: "message title",
    msgDesc: "message desc"
};

//you can push all the objects here before saving to the storage
//maybe you have a forEach here, pushing the objects? Who knows
msgArray.push(newMsg); 

//the array is now set in the storage
localStorageService.set("wimmtkey", msgArray); 

//the array obtained from local storage
var obtained_array = localStorageService.get("wimmtkey");
```

Comment: You don't need to stringify with this library, because the `set` function utilizes angular's `toJson()` method under the hood. Similarly, the `get` method `JSON.parse()`s the item to return. No need for that either.